# Oracle SQL. Как вывести N ячеек таблицы в строку без аналитических функций и иерархической конструкции

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Есть необходимость из таблицы со столбцом:

```
ID
1
3
6
8
9
11
23
```

... получить таблицу:

```
ID    Res
1      1
3      1,3,1
6      1,3,6,3,1
8      1,3,6,8,6,3,1
9      1,3,6,8,9,8,6,3,1
11     1,3,6,8,9,11,9,8,6,3,1
```

Понимаю, что звучит бредово, но такие были поставлены условия: создать запрос ***без использования Model, аналитических функций, регулярных выражений, иерархических запросов и рекурсивного WITH***. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ решить эту задачу при данных условиях?

Очень прошу, если вы знаете (хотя бы примерно), как это можно сделать, поделиться методом или названиями функций, которые могут быть применены.

P.S. PL/SQL не рассматривается

Comment: wm_concat можно использовать или тоже нет? :)

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы вас направили или чтобы за вас решили? ;)

Comment: Хотел бы получить направление. Точно, wm_concat!

Comment: "Точно, wm_concat!" - и не смущает, что она не официальная и является по сути примером pl/sql функции. Что сказано по этому поводу в задании?

Answer (score 7):

Перемножаем таблицу на саму себя, по такому условию, что бы к ID были выбраны все остальные, которые меньше его. После этого остается сгруппировать и собрать строку ID через запятую в нужном порядке (два раза, в прямом и обратном направлении):

```
with Tab(ID) as(
 select 1 from DUAL union all select 3 from DUAL union all select 6 from DUAL union all select 8 from DUAL union all
 select 9 from DUAL union all select 11 from DUAL union all select 23 from DUAL
)
select A.ID, trim(both ',' from
              LISTAGG(B.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by B.ID) || ',' ||
              A.ID || ',' ||
              LISTAGG(B.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by B.ID desc) )
  from Tab A
  left join Tab B on B.ID < A.ID
 group by A.ID
 order by A.ID
```

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ffb59/1)

Comment: не считается ли `listagg` аналитической функцией?

Comment: @Viktorov listagg может быть аналитической, при наличии предложения `over()` или может рассматриваться как обычная аггрегирующая, при отсутствии over и наличии group by (или без него). По хорошему это обычный sum() только для строк. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035

Comment: Желание подавить лишние запятые наверное возникнет - `trim(both ',' from ',1,')`.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо, а то лень было лезть вспоминать чем удалять :)

Answer (score 5):

Похожий вариант, но с одним использованием listagg и без лишних запятых:

```
select t.id, LISTAGG(q.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY q.ord, q.id * q.ord2)
from test t 
join (
    select id, 1 ord, 1 ord2
    from test 
    union 
    select id, 2, -1 ord2
    from test 
) q on t.id >= q.id and q.ord = 1 or t.id > q.id
group by t.id
order by t.id;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76a3bd/1)